# Sync the start of execution in multiple Android devices

Tags: android, mobile

I would like to start executing a function at the same time in multiple Android devices and would like to know your opinion on what would be the best way to achieve this.

The best I could think is over Bluetooth, with multiple sockets one for each device. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't Bluetooth a P2P connection? I don't think you can connect to multiple devices at the same time. However, you can send a message via Bluetooth to each device (one by one), saying "execute at HH:MM:SS". Then each device can match the current time with the message time & execute the function. I am assuming that you can set the time on all the devices to the same.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Yes, over bluetooth you can only have one active connection at a time, but if the connections are fast enough you may not notice the difference.

Maybe sending an offset and then recalculate it for the next device with the time you spent sending the previous message.

Comment: You can certainly go with the "offset" approach if you aren't that bothered with precision (because different connections will vary in their connection time). However, if you want exactness, you might try the approach I suggested.

Comment: I think I'll use NTP to sync the clocks and follow as you said. Thanks for your help.